# While adding a div content into another div on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code --

```
<div id="div1">

    this is div 1 

    <form class="thisformtobeaddeverytime">
    <!-- this form to be add on click #btn1 -->
    </form>

</div>

<div id="div2">

    this is div 2 

      <form class="thisformtobeaddeverytime">
             <!-- this form to be add on click #btn2 -->
      </form> 

</div>

<div id="showtheaddedform">

          //here my form will be push on click to button

</div>

<button type="button" id="btn1">Add the form1</button>
<button type="button" id="btn2">Add the form2</button>

// the click function in my js file are as -

$(document).on("click","#btn1",function(){
          $("#showtheaddedform").append($("#div1").html());
});
$(document).on("click","#btn2",function(){
          $("#showtheaddedform").append($("#div2").html()); 
 });
```

**now the problem is --**

On click #bun1 it's adding the content of #div1 into #showtheaddedform (i.e. the form attribute and all element inside form), like

```
<div id="showtheaddedform">
      <form class="thisformtobeaddeverytime">
         <!-- this form to be add on click #btn1 -->
      </form>
</div>
```

**but when I'm clicking #btn2 it's adding only the element inside the form , like**

```
  <div id="showtheaddedform">
     <!-- this form to be add on click #btn2 -->
  </div>
```

[ NOTE : I've not written any kind of remove query ]

..any idea , how it's removing !!!

Comment: Your click events are not properly closed

Comment: the point is it's removing the form tag only..all other text input are available .

Comment: What do you mean ***it's removing the form tag only*** Do you want move `div` element as well?

Answer (score 1):

Both your buttons have the same id. Also there is a syntax mistake in

```
$(document).on("click","#btn1",function(){
      $("#showtheaddedform").append($("#div1").html());
 }
```

add

```
); to it
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LLX6T/5/)

Actually Form tag is getting append to the div on second button's click. But in the UI it will not be shown as it doesnt have any tags or text in it. Try giving some text or tag in it. It will work

**EDIT**

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LLX6T/6/)

Comment: problem is not with those ... I've many text input in each form .. the point is it's removing the form tag only..all other text input are available .

Comment: @ChinmoyMaity its working fine, please have a look at the updated fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Your second button appears to have the wrong ID.

```
<button type="button" id="btn1">Add the form2</button>
```

Change to

```
<button type="button" id="btn2">Add the form2</button>
```

Comment: sorry ..that was a typo ..it's #btn2

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code in java script tag and also change your button id to btn1 and btn2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//alert("hi");
$("#btn1").click( function()
{
    $("#showtheaddedform").empty();
    $("#showtheaddedform").append($("#div1").html());

});
$("#btn2").click( function()
{
    $("#showtheaddedform").empty();
    $("#showtheaddedform").append($("#div2").html());

});
```

});